# how can i display different category._id under one page route in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i'm trying to display multiple categories under a route, clicking on the first category  display my products ,but when i click on another category it doesn't display the products until  hard refresh my page which now displays the lists of products under the categery._id
this is how i go to the category route

```
<nav class="navbar-end">
          <div
            class="pt-4 p-3"
            v-for="category in categories"
            :key="category._id"
          >
            <router-link :to="`/categories/${category._id}`">
              {{ category.type }}
            </router-link>
          </div>

        </nav>
```

this is my script tag to get the list of products under a category._id

```
<script>

import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "Product",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      category: {},
      categories: [],
      products: [],
      catID: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${this.$route.params.id}`,
        {}
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.category = response.data.category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error;
      });

    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        this.products = response.data.products;
        const catID = this.category._id;
        // this.products = this.products.filter(
        //  ({ category }) => catID === category._id
        // );
      })
      .catch(error => { 
        error;
      });
   
  },
 
  computed: {
    currentProducts() {
      if (!this.category._id) {
        return this.products;
      }
      return this.products.filter(
        ({ category }) => category._id === this.category._id
      );
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addProductToCart"]),
    logout() {
      localStorage.clear();
      this.$router.push("/login");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is my category route

```
  {
    path: "/categories/:id",
    name: "Category",
    component: Category
  },
```

i get the products after clicking the first category ,but clicking another category changes my category.id url but doesn't update until i hard refresh ,which now displays the list of product please how can i display the products on the same category.id route with hard refresh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because the code in the `mounted` block gets executed only once
To do a fetch everytime when you select a different category, you can define a method that does the api call and trigger it inside `watch` and `mounted`

```
watch: {
 '$route.params.id': {
   handler(newVal) {
     this.loadCategories(newVal);
   }
  }
},
mounted() {
 this.loadCategories(this.$route.params.id);
 axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/products`, {})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);

        this.products = response.data.products;
        const catID = this.category._id;
      })
      .catch(error => { 
        error;
      });
},
methods: {
 loadCategories(id) {
  axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${id}`,
        {}
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.category = response.data.category;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        error;
      });
  }
}
```